# cypher multiple optional matches with where conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a three objects in database: Person, Country and Car, that can be created with

```
create (:Car { name: 'car-987' })
create (:Car { name: 'car-876' })
create (:Country { name: 'country-123' })
create (:Country { name: 'country-234' })
create (:Country { name: 'country-345' })
match (cnt:Country { name: 'country-123' }), (cr:Car { name: 'car-987' }) create (cr)<-[:HAS_CAR]-(:Person { name: 'person-abc' })-[:LIVES_IN]->(cnt)
match (cnt:Country { name: 'country-234' }) create (:Person { name: 'person-bcd' })-[:LIVES_IN]->(cnt)
match (cr:Car { name: 'car-876' }) create (cr)<-[:HAS_CAR]-(:Person { name: 'person-cde' })
```

I'm selecting Person objects with optional country and car information

```
match (prs:Person)
optional match (prs)-[:LIVES_IN]->(cnt:Country)
optional match (prs)-[:HAS_CAR]->(cr:Car)
return id(prs) as id, prs.name as person, cnt.name as country, cr.name as car
order by person asc
```

The result is:

```
╒════╤════════════╤═════════════╤═════════╕
│"id"│"person"    │"country"    │"car"    │
╞════╪════════════╪═════════════╪═════════╡
│62  │"person-abc"│"country-123"│"car-987"│
├────┼────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┤
│63  │"person-bcd"│"country-234"│null     │
├────┼────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┤
│64  │"person-cde"│null         │"car-876"│
└────┴────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┘
```

The problems starts if i'm trying to use some conditions. For example i need to get only records where country.name contains '4' OR car.name contains '6'.
With such conditions i expect to get:

```
╒════╤════════════╤═════════════╤═════════╕
│"id"│"person"    │"country"    │"car"    │
╞════╪════════════╪═════════════╪═════════╡
│63  │"person-bcd"│"country-234"│null     │
├────┼────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┤
│64  │"person-cde"│null         │"car-876"│
└────┴────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┘
```

How can i achieve it?
If i'm trying to use WHERE inside OPTIONAL MATCH

```
match (prs:Person)
optional match (prs)-[:LIVES_IN]->(cnt:Country) where cnt.name contains '4'
optional match (prs)-[:HAS_CAR]->(cr:Car) where cr.name contains '6'
return id(prs) as id, prs.name as person, cnt.name as country, cr.name as car
order by person asc
```

getting not expected results:

```
╒════╤════════════╤═════════════╤═════════╕
│"id"│"person"    │"country"    │"car"    │
╞════╪════════════╪═════════════╪═════════╡
│62  │"person-abc"│null         │null     │
├────┼────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┤
│63  │"person-bcd"│"country-234"│null     │
├────┼────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┤
│64  │"person-cde"│null         │"car-876"│
└────┴────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┘
```

Was also thinking to use something like

```
match (prs:Person),
(prs)-[:LIVES_IN*0..1]->(cnt:Country),
(prs)-[:HAS_CAR*0..1]->(cr:Car)
where cnt.name contains '4' or cr.name contains '6'
return id(prs) as id, prs.name as person, cnt.name as country, cr.name as car
order by person asc
```

but this one don't return any records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, try keeping your OPTIONAL MATCHes, but use a WITH along with a WHERE clause to enforce the rest of your filtering:

```
match (prs:Person)
optional match (prs)-[:LIVES_IN]->(cnt:Country)
optional match (prs)-[:HAS_CAR]->(cr:Car) 
with prs, cnt, cr
where cnt.name contains '4' or cr.name contains '6'
return id(prs) as id, prs.name as person, cnt.name as country, cr.name as car
order by person asc
```